# Como resolvo esse problema do method create no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Bem, tenho um formulário onde contem um input em html de uma imagem. Quando eu mando o formulário para o Controlar, faço o tratamento da imagem, pegando o nome dele e upando para o diretório de imagens. Mais quando vejo no banco o nome da imagem não esta correta. Veja na imagem ao lado -> [image: O Nome da imagem no banco vai dessa forma, diferente do nome que vai para o diretório]

Então com esse problema não consigo buscar a imagem, já que os nomes não batem (O nome do diretório != do nome do banco). Vejam como estou fazendo:

```
if ($request->hasFile('imagem')) {

        $imagem = $request->file('imagem');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $imagem->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($imagem)->resize(100, 100)->save(public_path('/imagem/igreja/membros/' . $filename));

        $all = $request->all();
        $membro->imagem = $filename ;

        $return = $membro->create(
           $all 
        );

        if ($return)
            return redirect()->route('membro.index')->with('msg', 'Membro cadastrado com sucesso!');
        else
            return redirect()->back();
    }
```

As informações vão, mais a imagem não vai. Estou seriamente com medo de ter que fazer dessa forma:

```
$membro->create(['Imagem' => 'value','...' => '....'   ]  );
```

Porque eu tenho um formulário grande e sujaria meu controlller.

Comment: você esta preenchendo a variavel `$filename` antes do save, ou seja, pegando o diretório `tmp` da imagem. Monte o diretório que a imagem será armazenada, passa esse diretório para o método `save` e salva ele no banco.

Comment: Nessa linha ja estou com o nome da imagem. Possa ser que eu não intendi o que vc esta querendo dizer.
$filename = time() . '.' . $imagem->getClientOriginalExtension()
Logo depois eu pensei em atribuir o valor $filename no $membro->imagem
para depois gravar. mais ele não esta indo para o banco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema esta em você repassar toda coleção do request para o `mass assignment` do método create, sendo assim, ele transforma a instancia do file uploader em string, retornando o path. Faça o replace do input imagem pelo `$path` da imagem salva.

## Recomendação

NUNCA utilize o método `all()` para `mass assignment`de métodos do eloquent, isso é uma falha de segurança, sempre faça uso do método `only()` para especificar o que será repassado para o eloquent.

```
// se a imagem não existir, o membro não será criado
// mas a imagem não deveria ser um input obrigatório?
// você pode validar isso no request, leia mais aqui:
// https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation
if ($request->hasFile('imagem')) {
    $imagem = $request->file('imagem');

    // Para que você esta colocando esse time()?
    // Eu não salvaria só com time, fica muito sem padronização.
    // Eu utilizaria um package de geração de uuid, por exemplo
    // https://github.com/ramsey/uuid
    // salvaria: 396e0a22-74a9-4b18-b9f8-9f2d32b9b70c.jpg
    // ou
    // {userId}-time().extension
    $filename = time() . '.' . $imagem->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // Aqui você esta definindo como irá ficar o caminho
    // que a imagem será salva
    // p.x: /imagem/igreja/membros/1501865802.jpg
    $imagePath = public_path('/imagem/igreja/membros/' . $filename);

    // Você precisa fazer uma checagem se a imagem foi salva
    // e se ocorrer algum erro e não for salva? sem espaço no servidor
    // sem permissões de pasta
    Image::make($imagem)
           ->resize(100, 100)
           ->save($imagePath);

    // Troque o input imagem, que até agora é instancia de file uploader
    // troque pelo diretório da imagem desse usuário, que foi salvo acima.
    $request->replace(['imagem' => $imagePath]);

    // Defina aqui todos os inputs de seu formulário
    $fields = $request->only([
                        'name',
                        'imagem'
                    ]);



    // Não é recomendado utilizado o método all()
    // para preencher métodos de mass assignment
    $created = $membro->create($fields);

    if ($created == true){
        return redirect()
               ->route('membro.index')
               ->withMsg('Membro cadastrado com sucesso!'); // método mágico :)
    }

    // temos um problema de lógica aqui
    // se o membro não for creado, você apenas da o redirect back
    // mas não retorna nenhuma mensagem de erro
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63628/discussion-on-answer-by-juniorb2ss-como-resolvo-esse-problema-do-method-create-n)